# Synthesized NSMutableArray is returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsmutablearray, synthesize

So I've declared this in my appDelegate.h

```
       @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *featured;
```

I've synthesized it like so in my appDelegate.m

```
       @synthesize featured;
```

When I log that out in the appDelegate with the object stored in there, I get the value it's supposed to have

In a viewController.h file I have declared this

```
       @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *featured;
```

In the viewController.m file I've synthesized it like this

```
       @synthesize featured;
```

I then print out this line and get a null value

```
       NSLog(@"HERE %@", featured);
```

That same line prints out the correct value in my appDelegate.m file. I'm completely lost. I've set it up in the way I've done it for a previous class exercise. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I created the array in appDelegate.m file like so in a method I called loadFeatured

```
  featured = [NSMutableArray array];

for (id dict in tempArray)
{
    //NSLog(@"dict=%@",dict);

    NSString *shopName = [dict objectForKey:@"shopName"];
    NSString *drinkName = [dict objectForKey:@"drinkName"];
    NSNumber *likes = [dict objectForKey:@"likes"];
    NSNumber *dislikes = [dict objectForKey:@"dislikes"];
    NSString *review = [dict objectForKey:@"review"];        

    Featured *feat = [[Featured alloc] initWithName:shopName drinkName:drinkName likes:likes dislikes:dislikes review:review];
    NSLog(@"feat=%@\n\n",feat);
    [featured addObject:feat];
}

NSLog(@"there is %d featured",[featured count]);
NSLog(@"HERE %@", featured);
```

Comment: First of all, you don't need to use @synthesize any more. But in any case, using it doesn't create the object -- you have to alloc init it somewhere or set it equal to another array. What did you do in either of those classes to actually create the array?

Comment: Just updated with the code showing how I made my array.

Comment: Did you do something similar in your view controller?

Comment: No, aside from the synthesize, the only other line is the NSLog line that logs out featured which is inside of the viewDidLoad method

Comment: Well, that's why then -- you didn't create the array in your view controller. Did you expect it to, because it has the same name as the one in the app delegate?

Comment: Hmm, I thought it would work by just having the synthesize in the viewController, because I also declared the property again and I thought that should grab the value?

Comment: @synthesize  just creates the getter and setter methods for the property. It doesn't actually create the object that property points to. I'm not sure what value you expected it to grab. The two properties are completely separate -- the fact that they have the same name is irrelevant.

Comment: @barit I think you want a array which can be accessed any where in the program..is that so?

Comment: Hmm, I see. I'm not super well versed in objective-c, do you think you could point me in the right direction in going about grabbing the value of the array in the delegate class from the viewController. I did it this way because I had done something similar in class and that worked, but now I don't really know.

Comment: @VinayakKini That's the plan, I wanted to get the data from the appDelegate to the viewController and then display that in a label.

Comment: @barit i have posted the answer how to access it. hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way, how to access the data stored in the app delegate from your viewcontroller.

You need not synthesize the object in the viewcontroller. Just import your appdelegate file and copy the following code wherever necessary.

```
NSMutableArray * nArray =[ (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] featured];
```

The above code gives you the required array from the app delegate.Now you can make use of the nArray object to display the details in the console.

```
NSLog(@"%@",nArray.description);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say how to do this without knowing the structure of your app. You could pass a pointer to the array to your view controller, if you have access to that view controller from the app delegate. The other way is to get a reference to the app delegate in your view controller, and then access its array. That can be done like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDel = [UIApplication shared application].delegate;
NSArray *myControllerArray = appDel.featured;
```

You'll need to import your app delegate into your controller's .m file to use this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already declared a property in appDelegate.h you can access it in the other viewController like this:

`#import "appDelegate.h"`

and you can access the value it by using something like this:

```
((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]).featured
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access an `NSArray` or any other object in any class, via `AppDelegate`, just create a property to access your `ViewController`, like so, in your `AppDelegate` class:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *viewController;
```

In your `ViewController` class:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate    *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ViewController *viewControllerREFERENCE = [appDelegate viewController];
```

Then you'll have access to any value on your ViewController, via AppDelegate.
I hope that helps you.